# Unable to expand navigation bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am making an adaptive navigation bar using bootstrap 4.
I am unable to get the top right button to expand the navigation bar.
Did I miss something?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-md fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/Placeholder.png"></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
```

[image: website]

Edit: I have now provided menu as the id in the class "collapse navbar-collapse"

Still didn't work

Comment: You didn't provide menu in Your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incomplete, but as I can see you don't have a HTML element with the ID attribute of equals to `menu`.

(you define in your button `data-target="#menu"`, then this would be the element to be expanded).

Also, check the [exemple of Navbar implementation of Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/), the last one is very similar to yours.

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem, I forgot to provide the JQuery Script source.